# Using QSettings with data stored in a QByteArray, or QIODevice?

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray, qsettings, qiodevice

I have data in ini format that was originally written using `QSettings` (and so it contains some `QSettings`-specific syntax) that is stored in a `QByteArray`. I'd like to be able to read and write to it using `QSettings`. Unfortunately, out of the box `QSettings` only seems capable of working with files specifically, and can't be used with a `QByteArray` or an instance of a class that derives from `QIODevice` such as `QBuffer`.

So far, I've found two ways of dealing with this:

1. Dump the data temporarily into a file, probably using `QTemporaryFile`, and read that using `QSettings`
2. Create a custom implementation of `QAbstractFileEngine` that can read from the data in the byte array as though it were a file, as suggested in [this ten year old thread](https://forum.qt.io/topic/832/qsettings-working-on-a-qbytearray). However `QAbstractFileEngine` is no longer public in Qt 5 and so this is a not a viable option.

I'd like to avoid writing this data to disk if at all possible. Ten years have gone by since that old thread was posted. Is there a better method available now?

edit: For the time being I settled on using `QAbstractFileEngine` even though it's private in Qt 5. At least it's still around as of Qt 5.15. If it's ever removed I'll update my code to use a different method. I'm going to keep this question open, though, in case someone can answer with another viable method that doesn't use `QTemporaryFile`.

edit 2: QAbstractFileEngine only works for reading settings. Writing settings using QSettings unfortunately always assumes the file is a native file.

Comment: On one hand the data is originally written using `QSettings` and stored in a `QByteArray`. On the other hand, `QSettings` can't be used with a `ByteArray`. Which one is true?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve what you want by registering your own format. You provide your own read/write functions, so you can do anything you want inside them. The [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#registerFormat) provide an example for using an XML format. You can easily modify this to write into a QByteArray.

```
// Buffer to store settings
QByteArray someBuffer;

bool readSettingsFromBuffer(QIODevice &device, QSettings::SettingsMap &map)
{
    // Ignore "device" and read from someBuffer instead.
}

bool writeSettingsToBuffer(QIODevice &device, const QSettings::SettingsMap &map)
{
    // Ignore "device" and write to someBuffer instead.
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const QSettings::Format BufferFormat =
            QSettings::registerFormat("buffer", readSettingsFromBuffer, writeSettingsToBuffer);

    QSettings settings(BufferFormat, QSettings::UserScope, "MyCompany",
                       "MyApplication");

    ...
}
```

Comment: This gets me halfway there. I could use a third party ini parser (or even write my own) but unfortunately I need to be able to read ini data that was already written out using QSettings, and QSettings has some internal mechanisms for serializing various Qt types (such as QByteArray, QStringList, and so on) that aren't exposed publicly. So I'd still need a way of converting between a QVariant and its string representation using the same method that QSettings already uses.